# How can you add a standard light fixture to a ceiling fan?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

How can I take a regular old ceiling mount light fixture - such as the one below - and add it to a ceiling fan?

Example light fixture: 
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0135HNWBI?pf_rd_p=d1f45e03-8b73-4c9a-9beb-4819111bef9a&pf_rd_r=7FY04S0478FXCJA1SEXA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0135HNWBI)
[image]

I can see in the customer reviews that someone has mounted it to a ceiling fan, but sadly the person gave no information, only a picture:
[image]

Any idea how I'd do something that?

Do you think they took a ceiling fan that already had a light similarly sized to the light fixture and simply replaced the lamp shade?

Or is there some way (assuming I could modify/physically mount the light fixture to the bottom of the ceiling fan) that you can pass wires for lighting up through the center of the ceiling fan into the ceiling?

I also see that there are Ceiling Fan Fitters - but none look like they'd really accommodate a lamp shade like this one (for example, they have pull chains at the bottom that can't be removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions, and it sounds like a viable and fun project. Some things you'll need to consider are: how do you want to turn the light on and off? If you currently have a fan that turns on with a wall switch, do you want the light to come on at the same time? Always? Typically, ceiling fans are pre-wired for a light kit, so you wouldn't have to worry about getting the wires all the way through the ceiling fan to the ceiling box. They're already up there. However, if you look at the instructions at Lowes.com (https://www.lowes.com/projects/build-and-remodel/install-a-ceiling-fan/project), you'll see there are a black, a blue, and a white wire at the top of the fan motor unit where these conductors are to be tied into the house wiring. The black is for the fan, the blue is for the light and the white is the return path (AKA "neutral") for both. [image: https://www.lowes.com/projects/images/how-tos/Heating-Cooling/replace-a-ceiling-fan-inline-ball.jpg]Usually when we install fans, if there is only to be one wall switch, we tie the blue and black together with the hot switchleg from the wall switch. But then we would use pull chains to control each load independently. It sounds like you might want to stay away from pull chains, that is, if you do not think you'd be able to modify your shade to allow a couple of pull chains to drop down through the bottom.

In another scenario, if there are two separate switches to control fan and light we keep the black and blue conductors separated from each other at the ceiling j-box, tying each to its own switchleg. This would be closer to ideal for you, but you'd have to ensure you have the third insulated wire up there in the j-box or else you'll need to fish another cable in and down to the location where you want to install the extra switch. One more thing to consider is the fan pull chain is normally where you control the speed of the blades. I'm wondering if the set-up in the picture from the customer review included a remote control kit option--something that would eliminate the need for pull chains as well as a third conductor. A remote unit can select fan speeds as well as turn the light on and off independently, although they are usually a pain to install and you'll need to make sure you get one that is compatible with your particular fan.[image: data:image/jpeg;base64,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]

Now onto the installation of your light on the fan. The lowes.com article I mentioned above walks you through the steps of attaching a light kit to a fan with no previous light kit, but it doesn't explain modifications. When you get to step one, loosen and/or remove the screws around the very bottom of the fan to pull out the switch housing cover plate.[image: https://www.lowes.com/projects/images/how-tos/Heating-Cooling/replace-a-ceiling-fan-inline-attach-light.jpg] The picture above shows the light kit already attached but indicates the correct screws. In the following picture, they've removed the plate and already attached the light kit. It attaches by removing a small plastic plug and screwing the all-thread pipe into the bottom of the plate and securing it with a lock nut.[image: https://www.lowes.com/projects/images/how-tos/Heating-Cooling/replace-a-ceiling-fan-inline-light.jpg]
For your project, you'll just have to adapt the stem of the lamp to this plate, and I'm guessing it might just fit without any further modifications, but if it doesn't and you have to drill the hole out larger to accommodate the stem, just be sure to secure it so that it will not wiggle as the fan vibrates. You may have to use an extra lock nut on the bottom. From there, you may have to clip off the connectors from the blue and white wires inside the fan and wire nut them to your lamp cord conductors. 
By the way, speaking of lamp cords, I don't know if your light fixture will have an actual lamp cord (the kind that has to be pulled apart to separate the two conductors) but if it does, be careful: lamp cords are designed to be polarized for safety. There is a smooth side and a rough or ridged side. [image: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxASEhUSEhEVFhUVFhcWEBMXFxcYGBIVFxUWFhUVGRUYHSggGBolHRUWITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODUsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGi0lHyYtKy0tLy0tLS0tLS0tLS4vLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0rLTUtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0rLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAIcBdQMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQQCAwUGBwj/xABFEAABAwICBAkKBAQEBwAAAAABAAIDBBESIQUGMUEHEyIyUWFxgdEUFkJVkZKTobHBQ1KC8FNyouEjRGKyFRczVGODwv/EABoBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQb/xAAzEQEAAgIBAgQFAwIFBQAAAAAAAQIDERIEIRMxQaEUIlFScQVTYTKRM0JygbEjwdHw8f/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A+4oCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICCCUEYh0oaTiCE9kYh0oJxBBGMdKbDGEI7hcFNhjHSqem04gibMQRZ7eZdBKAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg1zbFJSZ08XTsNPVXnYX8bNIaedkhtYi7YZIycsLW2FgRkDkTZcpu+nNK58e6TrURv8A8sKbWKsfxNuJbx8UsjeQ9wZxJbe4xjFiDhllY3N3b7W8zCz0lIrMb3rXu3+c1Q+Nro2xtIpvKZA+7g7OwjaQW2GRu4g2u3Iqc52z8JEW1v10V+tEzWvkY1gZFFHLIxwcXyCTNzWlpAaQ29iQ656FLXkr0XKa9/OZj+yjpSuqXmUcY2zayBkQwkYQcDhiscwMWY39I3K2nbviw4663H+Wz0mgtJSSidsmEvgmdES0FrXgMY4OAJcW3x237Ful+0vBmxRTjr1jbzddrBLJBO2VrQ5nFERgTMcAZsOb72eMgQ5pF8wQs8/leynR15VnfpP/AA3ae0lNI6wLWxx1lPHa5D3f4jC44gbWz5lt23cmS8x5L02CK7m3fdZlb0TrLLLOBxfIdLJGAI5LxhhcA90psx1y3NoGV7XO1Wl9x3efN0k1je/SJegotKwTPkZHIHOhdhlA9FxF+/eLjeCNoK7RMPLkwWxxFr+vkvtU25+fdkgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIMXtuhE6c2PQVO1+NsTQ65dlewc7nENvYE9NlnjDpGa/1ZR6FgGC0bRxbXNj/ANLX2xtHUbK8YPFvETESwk0BTOa1hibhYMLBnk0+j1t2ZHLJZ4wsZ8m97Zz6FgeQ50TSRYC/QDdoI2EAjYVrjCeNfXmiXQkDnF5jBcXNcTnm5nNcesWGaREQsZrx/Zvp6BjMeFjRxjscn+txABcenIAdyRWIiWLZbWjv6KjNXqUNc0QswvtiGe44gOqxzyWeEa03PUZO3dFRoamfJxjoml9w++/Ewgsda9ri21XUeqfEZKVnjPpp5TWSvjbP5NQxNfWvJLiObBiHKedzTbfbffeL8b63qr6fT4bzijLnnVPef4h6HVHVxlHGRiL5JDinlN7yOz6djRc27Ttuutaa83i6zqJzW/iPKPo9A1b1DyMkUQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQQgxxIaeL1s1ikx+R0Yx1T9pGyAZXcScrgG+ey+82B5Xya+Wvm+n0fSVrHj5f6P+XT1R1ajo4yL45X5zTHa92ZO3O1ye3aVceOKOHWdXbqLbjtWPKHoQ1dHj82QQSgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIOdNpiFs4pi4ca5pe1m8tva/yd7p6Fibxzirfg3mvOI7OHrdrP5OGwwN4yqlyiiGYbcHlvt6IAOW/qFyM5MsR8tfN7ej6Scm7WnVY85Tqbq86mxSzPMlRNYzvJNupoHQCT87WFlcePUb9U63q/GiKVj5Y8nqQz99K3DwSyVCyJpKKICAghAugXQEBAugICgKhdQRiTYYk7iC9UUqjTdMw2dMwHouFnnX6txjtPovNddahhkoCoICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIIQfJ+EDSrqfSrZYw0vbTNa3Ecmlz5m3PZkdy8efL4eWNR6P1H6V08dR0U0tv8Aq32/DRq7rDRUpdK7jauskxcc9jLiMC3JaX25FyBcXvt2WCUyViZ7bsx1XQ5r/J2pT03/AO+b6foypMkcchjLC9oc5hsS24va4yP77F7K+T81kr4c6q6AUgSqIJQLoF0C6BdARUXTaaYmUbyB3+KbNNb6yMbXtHa4KbXiqzaepGc6oiHa9o+6cjipza46Obtq4u5wP0U5HCVSXhB0Y3/MA9jXn7JyIpLn1HClo9vNEr+xgHzcQpya4S5VRwuM/DpHHoLngfIA/VXkcXJq+FKudzIYmddnOPzP2WZu1FXGq9dNJybakt/lAaPkFmbGu71Gr2uFc+ANDRI5t28ZZxJGRF9181icto8nWMVJ801X/FJzmyU3/SB3LnyvZ01jqyptSaySxeQ3tde3cFqMMz3Jz1iNPpNFEWMa0m5a0AnpsLL01eO0wsLTKUBAQEBAQEEIJQQgIJQQSmk2i6aNmJFaZquNvOkY3tcB9Sgpzaw0TOdVQDtlZ9LqbhdSoy68aMbtq4+7EfoFJtEHGVOXhG0Y38Zzv5Y3/cJzheEqr+FCgGwTH9A+uJORwlVk4VqX0YJj24QmzhLiaU14oKhxdJo3G425TnNucNw3duxH2qTFd7074uoy4u1LTH4RTcITIgBDo+NgAsLHYOi7R1D2LEREM2ve07taZbDwn1Po0rPa8rcTpz00P4TK87IYx3E/dNnFqdwjaTOxsY/R/dOUrxhpk180qfSYOxrVOUrxhXdrnpU/5i3ZhTlJxhpdrdpPfVn2t8FOUnCGmXWrSB21j+4j7BOUrwhVdrHW/wDdye8VPEWMcNbtP1Z21cnvlPEXw2t+mqg7aqT33eKnM4K0le886Z57XOP3TmcGh9Q3e4n5/dNrphxzP3ZTZpImG4E/vqTcjNhcdkbz+kp3lG5lLOebA893s29dlfPsk2rC/SavV8nNpz9fpfNZn5e0tTaI7zXs7NJweaSktiAb03I8b/L2rcV258tTv0d2g4KHHOaoHWGgnwWoxwzOWJe81Z1fhoozHFchzsTidpNrfZbiIhibRLsZKpuBDcJuhuC6G4LobguhuC6G4LobguhuEXUmQxKRY21mS2ZWuyxEzbUIEvXdDUxbunjOv+5SErEzKYn33ju/f7si6mPNsRH5+l180m7bUuHYGj7Lhys9HCqnJrRXu21cvc8j6JyscaqU+k538+d57ZD9ym7GqtBlYedK2/W6/wB07+pqE8fT/wAQdyqLMFTS7SXHsurEfU/DpxVVHuhcfb09C1EQxMy7dNUQgXbRA5XBLc1eLPKUVekZLXbRm+3KM+CcTlLjVemKs3HkzxbZyWi3UpMNQ5stZVk/9Fw/UPFZ01Cq6eqPoD31F0hzqroZ3uPgmzTAiovtZ7T4KbXSeInPpt9hVGs08m+Zvu/3QQ2nd/Gb7P7pKs/Jf/N8goMvIx/H+QViISZlkykaPxr9RamqpuW5kMY3sPaCPumoNy2MEY9CI+3xTUG5XaapgaeVTsI34Tb7Fa3Vj5nao9L6KbbHSS9ZDmeASJqfM9DQac0Fvikb/M1xHtatbqkxZ3afSehSLsfB3g39hTVZT5tw8Vp3XOricY42U8QJfgkjDXEsJIYQfRIsdo2jYvHnz2r2iH6n9O/S+kzRFslu/wBPJytCax1QqhOXGd9nWbJLgYMWEE7Q3dzQM9tsrrlhz2337vpdd+mdPGKKUjX4jb3cWtGmXAOboxpaQCCJWkEEXBBvmOtezxMmu1Y/u/OT0XRx2nL3/DPzi036qHxW+KkZMv2+7PwnReuX2POLTfqofFb4q88v2+58J0P7vsecem/VY+K3xTnl+33X4Tof3fY849N+qx8VvinPL9vufCdD+77HnHpv1WPit8U55ft9z4Tof3fY849N+qx8VvinPL9vufCdD+77HnHpv1WPit8U55ft9z4Tof3fY849N+qx8VvinPL9vufCdD+77HnHpv1WPit8U55ft9z4Tof3fY849N+qh8VvinPL9vufCdD+77HnHpv1WPit8U55ft9z4Tof3fY849N+qh8VvipOTJH+U+C6CfPL7LuhdNaUkmayfR4ijN8b+MBw7bWAJutVvf6OHVdP0uGm8V+X+zqa00olp3xmRsZcWBribAnG0iMi4uHWLSBtByzW7PL09tZInX1eeg0oYQIo2RwP8qZFMG8qMY2YrsGQB5uVgsRfb2x0/Lv/ABMpdXPmkpeMILo62WMOAtiwxPF7biAbEDeCpu0a/LdMNa0yf6Yn+8w16s1cpkpWscI2EVbnRNbZpLKktvnmOd7XX3hTFaZmN/ymfDWKXn6cfeHu8ZXofK0/LH/Do/y/Mrz8np0ybQw/lb802mm9lLB+Vg/SrEpMQtRtp9+D3Lqs6WIpacbr/wDr8ShwX6XSsDLWY47fwmfdWJ0k1/l04Nbi3mRydVmxD6BXknFM+uNY4Wbx4/W0f7WpzOMOdNpiufkeM73nwTnJxhSlFW7aHd7z4KamWtw1jR1Qd39RTUnKGxug6h3on+o/RTjJyhvj1Sq3bI3e65OMnOIWI9Raw/hu93xV4s+Kts4Oa0+gf6U4nitrODWr/Kfa1XieK3M4Mars/UnE57bm8F1T0t99TivI/wCVlR0t98pwPE0xdwW1X5m++nA8VqfwYVY2Edz/ABCcE8Vol4Nq4bG3/UCnBfFVZOD+vb+E49zSpxOahNqnWs2wv9x32TisXUZaCdvOYRbtHyKnFeTQ5sg2tP771JjRyYtqnDYSP3/ZSZ36OtMtq+UpM4IzDSLZ5AbdnNsseHWZ3p7afqOWtdcpd2h1yroWCOKcsY3mtDIyBvORZ03PeutZ08N/+pO3Qi4S9JN/Ehf/ADRW/wBrgrzcpprs9JqnwjySyltWImMw3D2YhZ18gQScj1KxZPDl7ePWGkdsnjz67fVai0JOO8LTa+A7JY/fb4rXKGPnj0WGPadhB7DdWIhJmWyyillULIFkCyBZAshPcLR0INNRTska5j2Ne1ws9rgHNcDtBByISY2VvMd4cmr1dgcImsYyNkcgkMbWNDX5OBaWiwscR3LHB3x9TaInu6cWjYGhjWwxtEZvE0MaBGcxdoA5JzOzpW3PxL9+8sW6KphgtBEOLJdFyG/4bnElzm5ckkkkkdJU1BOS89tyt2VYfHWcF1TvA98Ln4bp4ixHwXzb8Hvn7JwPEXI+C9298f8AUfsrFU5rMXBk3fI3uaT9SrxZm0y2TahUsVuMnDbnCLtaLkg5C7tuScXSsWnydGDUOl2mR57MA/8AlIiHOd70tN1Iox/EP6h9gtdk3KxHqjRD8Mnte77FOx3bmatUY/Ab3lx+pTUHdvZoWmGyCP3GqCzHQxN2RsHY0BBuEbRuHsVGSAoCAqCAgICAgICiCK1ywMcLFoPTcA/UIrn1Gr1G/nU8fc23zFk1BtyqnULR7/w3N/ld43TUHJyqvgupHc2R7e0Nd4LM1hebmz8Ew9Ccd7SPoVODU2+jnT8FVSObIw95H1U4JF3W1W4OXRueaqxaQMAaQcwc75bLWWuC+Lp7AavxAW4mB1tgLLfPNZnERlu41VqRA8YjCWk54Y5AA3q5TbLM4pdY6iVjVfVd1LO54e8scyzWuIJa7FnmDYjrsFaY7V85c8mSLeUPWLs46SiiAgICAgIMVSJESGSiiAgICAgxcm0mNvDcLcLTRXLc2yswu/Lc2PtGS8/Vf4W32/0GZ+MrG3ktUNZ62njLsJnp2EiRoJL4bgPD7m5DCC6194cMsivLhyXmu49H1v1XoemveYr8l58vSJfUNA6bp6uPHBJiF7HKxaegtOYP7GS92O85I3L8r1PS5cXy383WaukOLJAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEGLkTUy83wggHR9RcA8jk9Trix6u1c89ZtTT3fptojqaWj0l4PRw8gNDVgnyeqhjZUtvljLMQcQTmSLno5Ls87Lzf4VY+k+b7efP8ZW9Lf11mZrP8er6do7RsEWJ0MbG8YcTiwAB3QezsyXrjURGn5vJbJeON7eToxha1pyjfqzRRAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQQ5WDemmaIOBBAIORB2EHaCN4QjdO9XO05oiOpgfA8clwytuIsQcuggGy53xxasu/T574skZHA4ONLSFklHO4mameW5m5cy/JN95GzebWvtXHBeZrMT5w936n09dxmx/027/ifo9s0r0vlJQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBBBQLIQwe1I3tmZn1fP8AXukfRzx6TivcOayqAJs+M2ABBuMJsG5bywjO5XmvXWTnHk+7+n2jqKT0tvzH5/8Aj3dDUtkja9puHAEHtF16KzuNvj5KzW01mPJE9fEw2fIxp6C4A+wlNpFZmNtwlFrqs996TjRIk4wJM6WJ3LCOoab2N7Eg2I2jIjtukrpnxgRnfdi2dpvY3tkeo9HaioZUNOw33ZdPQhMTE6ltBQSgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIMXKwk+SnpOgZPG+KQXY9pa4dRyyO49axaNumLLbFkjJX0VdWtECkp2wCRzwwmznWyBNw2w2AJEah0zZ4z5JvrW3mNY3vFTUuZAyUeTxh+I5tBMgxNbgditcki7TYZXXK23rwRWa13PqO0tLGxrYqgYIqNkschAcKl2bd4JwjCLhud5B3yckxEQ1OKlu8+c21+GzSGsU7GVBxBrmeT8W0hvJ43ADt2847Vq15WvSY7TXv58vZOktNVDZHYZWtDaqGEQlrTdj3MDnXtiuQ453sBu3rF7Ts6fpcVo1P2zP+8K2gaqaJ9w84Ja+qjdEWt/iSuxB1r4ri223VvWqzO42ubHimvbzisf3dXWrSs8MsfFvszCXSBojc/ntAJY8gllrjkG9zvUyXtvs8vT4qWrbfm58elJGOlawiPjK9sb5cDbtaYWuxG4s5xIawOcDbF1LUXl6MmCkxX/Tv3VKTSU8bRHESRJUVOJ7BHc4XbBxpDBmc9+RsFzpe3KI/mXbNjxZJ35aiv8A2e11aq3y07JJMOJwuS0tc12ZAcC0kWIAORsL7SvVvcPlZoiLzEOojkICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIIIQLIiMKGtNZpm3JsLkWJtmR0Eqabi0w1O0bCcIMbLN5nJHJ7Msu5JiJXnZMtBE44nRtcdly0E26LnckxEpzt9XKqtWGSTCV8jiA9j8GFlrszaA+2LDcB1r7Qs8Id6dVatdRHpp12UcY2Nbzi4ZDJx2ntNzmt6cJvMk1HG+xc1riM2kgGx6RfYnZItMMX0EZDmljSHG7wQCHHpI3nZ7Ea8SzE6NhLcBjaW3vhLRa/Ta21I0eJbe1qOMNFhsGwdA6EY82SAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIP/9k=]The hot conductor is always wired to the smooth side of the lamp cord. The neutral (white) wire should be spliced together with the ridged side of the lamp cord. If you just have a black and a white wire, just wire nut the black to the blue wire and the white to the white.

Comment: WOW. You rock. Thank you, this is amazing! 

The fan is for a cathedral ceiling so we'll have to do a remote control. We do have a fan there right now - but it's old and terrible, and so I'd look for a new fan with a remote control... POSSIBLY that already has a light to see if I could just replace the lampshade, but I am still not clear how that works (so hard without being able to see things - thank you for posting the internal pictures).

Q: I found another post saying it would be dangerous to attach a light that wasn't specifically compatible with the fan. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @AbbyFichtner, I wouldn't consider it dangerous as an electrician. But it might be dangerous if someone didn't know what they were doing. You may void manufacturer warranties if you go outside their options, and if the light you want to use draws more electrical current than the wiring can handle it would definitely be dangerous. In that case the blue and white wires would have to be upsized through the entire fan and into the ceiling box. As an electrician I would know how to do that, but I wouldn't want to. I would look for different options, such as lower wattage lamps or LED replacements.

Comment: "dangerous" in that some fans are not built to have lamps below them (much like most helicopters are not built to have the [*Kiowa Warrior's* radar dome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_OH-58_Kiowa) stationary above their blades) so on those, an installation would 't be feaible (spin the lamp? Lol)  Also, fans put out a lot of vibration, which any random lamp isn't built to endure.  That's not strictly an electrical problem, except that NEC does require you to consider such things as part of installation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the interesting bit you call a "lamp" is actually a *lamp shade*.   The guts with emitters and wires are pretty boring and look about the same.

Lamp shades are easily interchangeable on all sorts of lamps.  They simply own a fan that already has a light on it with the usual standard lampshade hub, and changed the shade.

However a shade on a fan had better be ready to deal with some *serious* vibration.  So that thing could have failed a week later and they just forgot to post that  fact on amazon.  People on social-media post [their successes, not their failures](https://sploid.gizmodo.com/this-is-why-you-shouldnt-take-peoples-lives-in-facebook-1595563358).

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I'm also wondering how it held up - I tried asking a question of the reviewer but I'm not holding my breath that they'll even see it much less respond. Figured I would have better luck asking here :)